# Highlight element in div and set it above other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, frontend

I'm currently trying to code some kind of a slider, some kind of showcase. To achive this i wanted to make a parent div which contains my three elements for the slide show. but i wanted two elements in the back and just one highlighted. Something like this: [image]
Orange would be the main div containing my three elements. the green on would be the highlighted in the foreground, and the black ones are in the background.

My problem: The only approach i've got so far looks like this:
[image]
Colors mean the same but there are now all centered and have all the same width.

Some code snippets:

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="spotlight">
        <div class="spotlight-back">
            <img src="assets\covers\large\6.jpg" />
            <img src="assets\images\testbild6.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="spotlight-back">
            <img src="assets\covers\large\4.jpg" />
            <img src="assets\images\testbild.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .25);
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.spotlight {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(30, 255, 0, .25);
    height: 85%;
    width: 95%;
    display: flex;
}

.spotlight-back {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(0, 26, 255, .25);
    height: 100%;
    width: 45%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.spotlight-back img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Some properties like background or border are just for testing purpose.

I hope you have some kind of solution for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply "z-index" property on the divs.
You can check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) how this property works.
For example, in your case the "green div" will have the "z-index" property set to a value higher that the other divs (something like 9, and the other 2 will have the value 8 for example)

Comment: yeah, i tried this as well but the div with the greater value won't get in front of the other ones. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Did you tried to set the position to absolute? Use [this](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/stacking-elements-with-z-index/) as reference

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by `positioning divs` and then using `z-index` property to bring the required `div` at the front of all.